# Are there line breaks in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm calling a function in Elm and some of the variable names I'm passing as parameters are kind of long, so I'd rather not put it all on 1 line. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

Normally, from experience with other languages, I'd imagine it might look something like this:

```
result =
    Dict.foldr \
        dataTransformationFunction \
        0 \
        initialStateDict
```

That obviously didn't work though. I tried using `|>` and `<|`, but I couldnt get anything using those to compile (since 0 and the other parameters arent functions that takes arguments, I couldn't pipe).

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there no way to add a line break in Elm code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to try the simplest option; you don't need a special character/operator to do a line break if none of your parameters require any (more) arguments.

This is perfectly legal:

```
result =
    Dict.foldr
        (myFunction)
        0
        initialStateDict
```

Comment: Yes, whitespace can be freely used in Elm. The only thing you need to be concerned about is indentation; if you start a new line, the compiler will sometimes get confused if it's indented less than other lines (and occasionally if the indentation does not match exactly a related line, but that's more to do with multi-line language constructs, e.g. `case`, not function expressions)

Comment: The simplest thing is to [use `elm-format`](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format) and allow it to format things. It will keep everything on one line until you add a line break, and then it will format the expression with line breaks (and the correct indentation).